# Count the azimuth after ball bounce

Tags: math, angle, azimuth

I have a ball. I know its azimuth and speed. I want to count the azimuth after a bounce (wall probably). Lets call the azimuth alpha. Image:

[image: angle]

I know the alpha. I know the wall azimuth. I need "?". Beta would be nice (but not so necesary).

Answer (score 5):

The `?` is `360-alpha` (in degrees).

This is because `beta = alpha`.

Comment: i thought beta == alpha but i wasnt sure :P what to do with horizontal wall?

Comment: @kittyPL Why the fact that the wall is horizontal should change geometry?

Comment: @Saphrosit I think it would change something... Becouse If I bounce by the horizontal wall, it cant be 360-alpha...

Comment: @kittyPL: If the wall is at an angle of `gamma`, then the final direction will be `2*gamma - alpha`.

Comment: @kittyPL: A horizontal wall won't change anything, because you're measuring alpha relative to the wall. When you turn the wall, the *relative* angles don't change, but if you need absolute angles (e.g., compared to straight up) you'll need to add the angle of the wall to the relative angle to get an absolute angle.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you r my god :) thanxxx much